# How to plot the derivative of NDSolve interpolation function?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

So I got a question. Everytime I use a derivative of a function during plotting or ongoing evaluation, it seems *Mathematica* misunderstands me, and just derives a value (a constant) which always results in a 0. What could be the problem? I demonstrate this with the solution of the Blassius boundary layer equation:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{
    D[f1[ξ], ξ] == g1[ξ], D[g1[ξ], ξ] == h1[ξ],
    D[h1[ξ], ξ] + f1[ξ]*h1[ξ] == 0, 
    f1[0] == 0, g1[0] == 1, g1[10] == 0},
   {f1, g1, h1},
   {ξ, 0, 10}];

f1rand = f1[10] /. sol1;
g1rand = g1[10] /. sol1;
h1rand = h1[10] /. sol1;

Plot[D[g1[ξ], ξ] /. sol1, {ξ, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[h1[ξ] /. sol1, {ξ, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to use `g1'[ξ]`

```
 Plot[g1'[ξ] /. sol1, {ξ, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Plotting `f1'[ξ]`, `g1'[ξ]` and `h1'[ξ]` in one plot,

```
Plot[Evaluate[{f1'[ξ], g1'[ξ], h1'[ξ]} /. sol1], {ξ,0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"f1'", "g1'", "h1'"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for. But if for instance I were to do this with 2 variables the '-command wouldn't apply anymore. How would I go about that?

Comment: @M.Pow What you mean by two variables?

Comment: Well I just asked that question because I have a differential equation where I have a function like f(x,y) and I would like to Plot the derivative of ∂f(x,y)/∂y

Comment: @M.Pow you need to share your complete try

Comment: Same example only 2D
`sol1 = NDSolve[{
   D[f1[x, \[Xi]], \[Xi]] == g1[x, \[Xi]],
   D[g1[x, \[Xi]], \[Xi]] == h1[x, \[Xi]],
   D[h1[x, \[Xi]], \[Xi]] + f1[x, \[Xi]]*h1[x, \[Xi]] == 0,
   f1[x, 0] == 0,
   g1[x, 0] == 1,
   g1[x, 10] == 0,
   f1[0, \[Xi]] == 0,
   g1[0, \[Xi]] == 0,
   h1[0, \[Xi]] == 0
   }, {f1, g1, h1}, {x, 0, 1}, {\[Xi], 0, 10}]

Plot[D[g1[x, \[Xi]], \[Xi]] /. sol1, {\[Xi], 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
Plot[h1[x, \[Xi]] /. sol1, {\[Xi], 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]`