# Derivative of solution of differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

Although there exists [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137188/how-to-plot-the-derivative-of-ndsolve-interpolation-function) question with an answer I am not able to adopt it to my problem.

I have a 1d Langevin euqation which I solve with `NDSolve`.

**How can I plot the derivative of the solution (see the plot below).**

Here is my code:

```
m = 6.137*10^-13; 
k = 1.5*m; 
stddev = Sqrt[2*k]*Sqrt[m];
whiteNoise = WhiteNoiseProcess[stddev];
randomForce[t_Real] := RandomVariate[whiteNoise[t]];

SeedRandom[1];
s = NDSolve[
   {m*x''[t] + k*x'[t] - randomForce[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}
   , x[t], {t, 0, 50}
   , StartingStepSize -> 10^-3
   , Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"
     }
   , MaxSteps -> Infinity
   ];

Plot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

I want to plot `x'[t]` vs. `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = NDSolve[{(m*x''[t] + k*x'[t] - randomForce[t]) == 0, x[0] == 0, 
    x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 50}, StartingStepSize -> 10^-3, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];

Plot[Evaluate[x'[t] /. s], {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... so the mistake is that I wrote in `NDSolve`: `x[t]` instead of `x`. The I can write also: `Plot[x'[t] /. s, {t, 0, 50}]`

Comment: @Lenoil Yes, that's with you needed to do.